# how to interact iframe to iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have some issues using JQuery on iframe

on the first iframe "dial", there is a

```
<input name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" type="text">
```

and on the iframe "jmb"

there is this button to alert what is the value inside the input on another iframe.

```
  $().contents().find().val(function(){
           alert();
});
```

wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If the Iframe is not on the same domain of your website, it will be for users like if it were a new tab in the browser: You can't interact or change the css of the iframe's content.

Else, hackers could take the password from facebook iframe for example.

Comment: When the source of the iframe is on the same domain, it does work!

Comment: In this case, we don't know if the iframe is on the same domain, but you are right to precise, I update my answer :)